# How to retrieve Firebase Data into TextView2 if TextView1 has specified content

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

i'm working on android app that fetch firebase data into textview2 if textview1
has specified content that related to firebase database table

**and here is the code**

```
private void FireBaseFetchedData() {

    // Receiving Data from ListView in SQLite_StockViewer Activity
    Intent intent = getIntent();
    String itemProduct = intent.getStringExtra(XlsxDB.Product);
    String ItemCode = intent.getStringExtra(XlsxDB.ItemCode);
    itemDesc.setText(itemProduct);
    itemCode.setText(ItemCode);

    mRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("PricesList");
    mRef.orderByChild("item_Code").equalTo(ItemCode).addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            for (DataSnapshot PricesListDataSnapshot : dataSnapshot.getChildren()) {

                PricesList pricesList = PricesListDataSnapshot.getValue(PricesList.class)

                Double PublicPrice = pricesList.getPub_Price();
                Double PharmacistPrice = pricesList.getPh_Price();
                Double TaxVal = pricesList.getTax_Val();

                pubPriceHProcess.setText(String.format(PublicPrice + "%s ج.م"));
                phPriceHProcess.setText(String.format(PharmacistPrice + "%s ج.م"));
                taxHProcess.setText(String.format(TaxVal + "%s ج.م"));

            }
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
}
```

the problem is there is no retrieved data 
and here is the console message

```
W/SyncTree: Listen at /PricesList failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
E/ContextImpl: IllegalArgumentException unbindService: 
I/System.out: [CDS]close[46215]
I/System.out: close [socket][/0.0.0.0:46215]
```

PricesList is Model Class

Comment: go to the firebase console and set the rules to true

Comment: exactly that what i did and i appreciate your advice

Comment: So you are gitting this error also

Comment: yeah but i remembered that i edited the rules the made it true again i also updated the codes of  
pubPriceHProcess.setText(String.format(PublicPrice + "%s ج.م")); 
phPriceHProcess.setText(String.format(PharmacistPrice + "%s ج.م"));
taxHProcess.setText(String.format(TaxVal + "%s ج.م"));

to

pubPriceHProcess.setText(PublicPrice + " ج.م");
phPriceHProcess.setText(PharmacistPrice + " ج.م");
taxHProcess.setText(TaxVal + " ج.م");

Comment: Do you give the permission on firebase database?